# It doesn't get the information right

Tags: html, django

The index.html doesn't show any error but doesn't show the information that it should.

When using tags there is no problem but when trying to get the information from the website, it simply doesn't show it.

```
                <div class="box">
                    <article class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <figure class="image is-50x50">
                                <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{ weather.icon }}.png" alt="Image">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-content">
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="title">{{ weather.city }}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="subtitle">{{ weather.temperature }}°F </span>
                                    <br> {{ weather.description }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

There are no errors, just the images not showing up

Comment: that `<br>` tag should be self-closed

Comment: like this? <br> {{ weather.description }}</br> .                It's still not working

Comment: @Scott no it shouldn't. That was only the case in XHTML, which is thankfully forgotten.